# How to make sequential id number in SQL Server start form 1 like in an MS Access database

Tags: c#, sql-server, auto-increment

When I use Microsoft SQL Server database and make a filed's data type as `uniqueidentifier` and use the function  `newid()` or `newsequentialid()`, it makes a new id that contain 32 value (hexadecimal value).

However, I need a way to make an auto-increment values starts with number 1 and so on just like auto-increment fields in MS Access.

Then I want to add other values using a C# program while the SQL Server adds the auto-increment field automatically without errors.

**Note**: I'm using SQL Server 2014, and Visual Studio 2015 perf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server method IDENTITY(1,1) to increment a column by 1 and starts from 1.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XXX](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `IncrementId` also to be the primary key you can create your table like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable](
    [IncrementId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OtherColumn] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SomeTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IncrementId] ASC
))
```

You than can insert values to the table like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (OtherColumn) VALUES ('SomeValue')
```

And this will give you a new row with an id that is the next in line so to speak

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Column and make it an identity column to the table
- To create an identity column, you may use the Management Studio or u can write a query.
- When Inserting data to the table, provide data to the columns, but not to the column created as identity column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an integer identity, you should use either TINYINT, SMALLINT, INT, or BIGINT column for your primary key. If you need GUID, you should use uniqueidentifier column type. You can't mix and match.

Regarding to the auto increment feature, if you need to insert a value manually, you should inactivate IDENTITY option on the table, insert your unique value, and then activate it again. I'm not really sure if it's a good idea to do this, but this is how it works:

```
-- Allows you to insert a value into identity column.
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SchemaName].[TableName] ON;

-- Do you insertion here...

-- Deactivates the identity value insertion.
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SchemaName].[TableName] OFF;
```